# Push-lock door?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary

What do you call a door that opens, closes and locks with a gentle push? Like the one you find on some cabinets or glove compartments. Push-lock door? Springing door? Magnetic door?

Comment: I've always called them "push-push" latches.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds silly, but seems to be correct. Are you American?

Comment: Yep, US Midwest.

Comment: As a semantic point, what you're describing doesn't actually *lock* when pushed. If it did, you wouldn't be able to simply push it open. (Not unless you think of it as a terribly inefficient lock that fails in its purpose.) When something *locks* it cannot be opened without a unique key. Anybody being able to open it by pushing it doesn't count. At best, it would be a *self-latching door*.

Comment: Thanks, but actually it does. It's a self-locking door that allows you to open it again with a push when it's safe to do so.

Comment: (This particular door. For the typical case, of course, you are right. Shouldn't have mentioned the locking at all, it's irrelevant for the question.)

Answer (score 2):

IKEA and other furniture manufacturers refer to these as 'push-open' doors and drawers

An example that I bought recently:
https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/storage-furniture/shelving-units-systems/best%C3%A5-storage-combination-with-doors-oak-effect-laxviken-white-spr-09140440/

Comment: Thank you for the link! Both "push-open" and "soft-closing" sound nice. The focus should really be on the self-locking mechanism though, so I'm hoping for more suggestions. I suppose there is a technical term for it as well.